# 'hierarchical' => true not bringing up the parent selector

Tags: wordpress, hierarchical

I want to display the parent select so I can select the parent for layout purposes.

This was un answered in the WordPress forum. It may be a missing or coming feature. Has anyone got this to work?

```
register_post_type('foo', array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Foo',
        'singular_name' => 'Foo'
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title', 'editor', 'author', 'page-attributes'
    )
));
```

Comment: Did you check page attributes on screen options ?

Comment: Yes I get the page attributes box but not the drop down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent select option will show only if you have at least 1 entry for this custom type.

Comment: Yip that was the problem. Thanks

Comment: I have 4 of my Custom Post Types created.
Still not seeing a choice to select a parent. I don't see why there would need to be anther entry to influence seeing pages to assign as the parent?